# Keyboard Navigation Clickable Issue Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard, click

I'm looking to expand on this Jsfiddle. I've got it working in my code, but I can't seem to make it 'Clickable'. I want the 'highlighted' box to be linked with a URL and for the user to only need to press the `enter` key to open the link of choice.

Any ideas?

Here's the fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6gea722/)

Comment: Did my anwer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute to each box of your HTML with the link where the user will be redirected if they hit "enter" on that box.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td class="selected" data="http://www.google.com">
    <td class="selected" data="http://www.yahoo.com">
</tr>
```

To then redirect the user to that link, you can add to your jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{    
   switch(e.which) {        
        case 37: // left
           move(1);
        break;
        case 38: // up
            move(2);
        break;
        case 39: // right
           move(3);
        break;          
        case 40: // down
           move(4);
        break;
        case 13: // enter
           var url = $('.selected').attr('data'); // get the url from the 'data' attribute from the currently selected box
           window.location.href = url; // redirect to the url
        break;
        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

I had some issues with running jsfiddle at all (just cannot open site for some reason). So I added the demo on CodePen [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OygOJL) - **However!** the redirect will not work on that site, so just try it on your end right away.